# Python DefaultDict implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hash-map

I found Python's `defaultdict` and `OrderedDict` incredibly useful, hence I attempted an implementation in JavaScript. As JavaScript objects only support string as key, it is not as powerful as the Python version. Can anyone suggest a way of using an object as a key in JS, like some kind of hash function? Also, is there anything wrong with this implementation?

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  function forEach(collection, func, thisArg) {
    var i;
    if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
      if (thisArg) {
        for (i = 0; i < collection.length; ++i) {
          if (func.call(thisArg, collection[i], i) === false) {
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        for (i = 0; i < collection.length; ++i) {
          if (func.call(collection[i], collection[i], i) === false) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (thisArg) {
        for (i in collection) {
          if (func.call(thisArg, collection[i], i) === false) {
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        for (i in collection) {
          if (func.call(collection[i], collection[i], i) === false) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return collection;
  }

  function deepCopy(obj) {
    if (typeof obj != 'object') {
      return obj;
    }
    var newObj = Array.isArray(obj) ? new Array(obj.length) : {};
    forEach(obj, function (v, k) {
      newObj[k] = v;
    });
    return newObj;
  }

  function assert(expression) {
    if (!expression) {
      throw 'Assertion faild';
    }
  }

  function implicitEqual(val1, val2) {
    return val1 == val2;
  }

  function explicitEqual(val1, val2) {
    return val1 === val2;
  }

  function deleteFromArray(arr, value, flag) {
    var ret = null;
    var method = flag == 'i' ? implicitEqual : explicitEqual;
    forEach(arr, function (val, index) {
      if (method(val, value)) {
        arr.splice(index, 1);
        ret = val;
        return false;
      }
    })
    return ret;
  }

  function createChildClass(parent, constructor) {
    constructor.prototype = deepCopy(parent.prototype);
    constructor._parent = parent;
    return constructor;
  }

  var DictionaryCollection = (function () {

    function DictionaryCollection() {
      this.dictionary = {};
    }

    DictionaryCollection.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
      this.dictionary[key] = value;
      return this;
    };

    DictionaryCollection.prototype.applyFunction = function (key, func) {
      this.set(key, func(this.get(key)));
      return this;
    };

    DictionaryCollection.prototype.get = function (key) {
      return this.dictionary[key];
    };

    DictionaryCollection.prototype.delete = function (key) {
      this.dictionary[key] = null;
      delete this.dictionary[key];
    };

    return DictionaryCollection;
  })();

  var DefaultDict = (function () {
    var DefaultDict = createChildClass(DictionaryCollection, function DefaultDict(defaultFunction) {
      if (typeof defaultFunction != 'function') {
        throw 'Default function must be a function';
      }
      DictionaryCollection.call(this);
      this.defaultFunction = defaultFunction;
    });

    DefaultDict.prototype.get = function (key) {
      return this.dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key) ? this.dictionary[key] : (this.dictionary[key] = this.defaultFunction());
    };
    return DefaultDict;

  })();

  var OrderedDict = (function () {
    var OrderedDict = createChildClass(DictionaryCollection, function OrderedDict() {
      DictionaryCollection.call(this);
      this.orderArray = [];
    });

    // @override
    OrderedDict.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
      if (!this.dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this.orderArray.push(key);
      }
      DictionaryCollection.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);
      return this;
    };

    // @override
    OrderedDict.prototype.delete = function (key) {
      DictionaryCollection.prototype.delete.apply(this, arguments);
      deleteFromArray(this.orderArray, key);
    };

    OrderedDict.prototype.getNth = function (index) {
      return this.dictionary[this.orderArray[index]];
    };

    OrderedDict.prototype.toArray = function () {
      var result = [];
      forEach(this.orderArray, function (key) {
        result.push([key, this.get(key)]);
      }, this);
      return result;
    };

    return OrderedDict;
  })();



  function testDC() {
    var dict = new DictionaryCollection();
    dict.set('a', 1);
    dict.set('a', 2);
    dict.set('b', 3);
    assert(dict.get('a') === 2);
    assert(dict.get('b') === 3);
    dict.applyFunction('b', function (val) {
      return ++val;
    });
    assert(dict.get('b') === 4);
    dict.delete('b');
    assert(dict.get('b') === undefined);
  }

  function testDD() {
    var dict = new DefaultDict(function () {
      return 70;
    });
    dict.set('a', 50);
    assert(dict.get('a') === 50);
    assert(dict.get('b') === 70);
  }

  function testOD() {
    var dict = new OrderedDict();
    dict.set('a', 50);
    dict.set('b', -1);
    dict.set('c', -3);

    assert(dict.getNth(0) === 50);
    assert(dict.getNth(1) === -1);
    assert(dict.getNth(2) === -3);

    var arr = dict.toArray();

    assert(arr[0][0] == 'a');
    assert(arr[0][1] === 50);

    assert(arr[1][0] == 'b');
    assert(arr[1][1] === -1);

    assert(arr[2][0] == 'c');
    assert(arr[2][1] === -3);

    dict.delete('b');
    assert(dict.get('b') === undefined);

    arr = dict.toArray();
    assert(arr[1][0] != 'b');
    assert(arr[1][1] !== -1);
    assert(arr[1][0] == 'c');
    assert(arr[1][1] === -3);
  }

  testDC();
  testDD();
  testOD();


  /*
   * example, using DefaultDict to count duplicates in an array
   */

  function int(value) {
    return value ? parseInt(value) : 0;
  }

  function countDuplicatesArray(arr) {
    var dict = new DefaultDict(int);
    forEach(arr, function (val) {
      dict.applyFunction(val, function (x) {
        return ++x;
      });
    });
    return dict.dictionary;
  }

  console.log(
    countDuplicatesArray([0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 8, 7, 5, 78, 8, 7, 8, 78, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5, 7])
  );

})();
```

Answer (score 3):

### Readability

Method `forEach` has 4 nested if-statements, with each statement doing things a little differently. This is a good candidate to refactor for compactness. There are 2 distinct ways you are looping arg `collection`, so I suggest to make a method for each of them.

---

#### (1) Complex Object

One for looping a complex object:

> ```
>   function forEach(collection, func, thisArg) {
>     var i;
>     if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
>        // .. 
>     }
>     else {
>        // .. this part
>     }
>   }
> ```

New method `propertyEach`:

```
function propertyEach(source, iteratee) {
  for (const key in source) {
    if (iteratee(source[key], key, source) === false) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return source;
}
```

As an example:

```
const myComplexObject = {
  name: 'Doe',
  firstName: 'John'
};

propertyEach(myComplexObject, (item, i) => console.log(i + ': ' + item));
```

yielding

```
'name: Doe'  
'firstName: John'
```

---

#### (2) Array

And one for looping an array:

> ```
>   function forEach(collection, func, thisArg) {
>     var i;
>     if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
>        // .. this part
>     }
>     else {
>        // .. 
>     }
>   }
> ```

New method `arrayEach`:

```
// courtesy of lodash
function arrayEach(array, iteratee) {
  var index = -1,
      length = array == null ? 0 : array.length;

  while (++index < length) {
    if (iteratee(array[index], index, array) === false) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

As an example:

```
const myArray = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
arrayEach(myArray, (item, i) => console.log(i + ': ' + item));
```

yielding

```
'0: 1'  
'1: 2'  
'2: 3'
```

---

### Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)

Then we can refactor your method to call either method depending on whether the source is an array and avoid redudancy when `thisArg` is undefined.

```
function forEach(source, func, thisArg) {
  if (thisArg === undefined) thisArg = source;
  if (Array.isArray(source)) {
    arrayEach(source, (item, i) => func.call(thisArg, item, i));
  } else {
    propertyEach(source, (item, i) => func.call(thisArg, item, i));
  }
}
```

As compared to the initial beast:

> ```
>   function forEach(collection, func, thisArg) {
>     var i;
>     if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
>       if (thisArg) {
>         for (i = 0; i < collection.length; ++i) {
>           if (func.call(thisArg, collection[i], i) === false) {
>             break;
>           }
>         }
>       } else {
>         for (i = 0; i < collection.length; ++i) {
>           if (func.call(collection[i], collection[i], i) === false) {
>             break;
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     } else {
>       if (thisArg) {
>         for (i in collection) {
>           if (func.call(thisArg, collection[i], i) === false) {
>             break;
>           }
>         }
>       } else {
>         for (i in collection) {
>           if (func.call(collection[i], collection[i], i) === false) {
>             break;
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
>     return collection;
>   }
> ```

The previous examples through your refactored method:

```
forEach(myArray, (item, i) => console.log(i + ': ' + item));
forEach(myComplexObject, (item, i) => console.log(i + ': ' + item));
```